# High Latency between DynamoDB and EC2 instance

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, amazon-dynamodb

I'm currently making some test with a node application installed on micro EC2 instance that performs some queries to DynamoDB but i have noticed that the total latency for a single is very high (10 seconds). If i try the same node application in my local machine the latency is around 600ms, that is also high but much better. I'm unable to ping dynamodb.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com but latency measured towards my EC2 instance which is also located in Ireland is around 45ms. Shouldn't dynamo latency be pretty much the same? I think i should be expecting at least <100ms latencies... I already checked cloudwatch and it shows a query time of 10-20ms for each DynamoDB getItem request. So I am trying to figure out what the problem is, the script that i'm trying is very simple and is shown below.

```
var test = function () {
    var _dyn = new AWS.DynamoDB({ endpoint: new AWS.Endpoint(config.db.host) });
    var params = {
          Key: {
              userId: { S: Date.now().toString() }
          },
          TableName: 'Users',
          ConsistentRead: false
    };
    var start = Date.now();
    console.log('Start Query');
    _dyn.getItem(params, function (err, userData) {
         console.log(err);
         console.log('End Query in ' + (Date.now() - start));
    });
}

test();
```

The test on my EC2 instance was made using free tier, is this a possible factor for the >10 seconds delays? For the test i have set the Dynamo table read and write capacity units to 100 to rule out provisioning related issues.

Comment: 10 seconds is, of course, completely unreasonable but you are likely going to have to dig deeper into the stack to explain it... think `tshark` and packet sniffing.  Intuitively, it sounds like a low level networking issue or misconfiguration.  Not being able to ping, however, is almost certainly a distraction.  That seems like a fairly standard configuration for AWS services.

Comment: How long does it resolve db host? Try to measure it with `time host db_host`

Comment: @aldebober I have try `time host dynamodb.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com` in ec2 istance and in my local computer in both the real value is beween 6 - 10 ms.